# How to create bitmap from byte array?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, arrays

I searched all question about byte array but i always failed. I have never coded c# i am new in this side. Could you help me how to make image file from byte array.

Here is my function which stores byte in array named `imageData`

```
public void imageReady( byte[] imageData, int fWidth, int fHeight))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I think all of the answers provided could work. However, my `ByteArray` contains raw bytes. That's those solutions didn't work for my code.

However, I found a solution. Maybe it will help others who have the same problem I had.

```
static byte[] PadLines(byte[] bytes, int rows, int columns) {
   int currentStride = columns; // 3
   int newStride = columns;  // 4
   byte[] newBytes = new byte[newStride * rows];
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, currentStride * i, newBytes, newStride * i, currentStride);
   return newBytes;
 }

 int columns = imageWidth;
 int rows = imageHeight;
 int stride = columns;
 byte[] newbytes = PadLines(imageData, rows, columns);

 Bitmap im = new Bitmap(columns, rows, stride, 
          PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, 
          Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(newbytes, 0));

 im.Save("C:\\Users\\musa\\Documents\\Hobby\\image21.bmp");
```

This works for 8bit 256 bpp (Format8bppIndexed). If your image has a different format you should change `PixelFormat` .

I still have a problem with colors right now. As soon as I solve that I will edit my answer for other users.

*PS = I am not sure about stride value but for 8bit it should be equal to columns.

Also this function works for me... it copies 8 bit greyscale image into a 32bit layout.

```
public void SaveBitmap(string fileName, int width, int height, byte[] imageData)
        {
            
            byte[] data = new byte[width * height * 4];

            int o = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
            {
                byte value = imageData[i];

                
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = value;
                data[o++] = 0; 
            }

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* ptr = data)
                {
                    
                    using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height, width * 4,
                                PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
                    {
                        
                        image.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".jpg"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi goGud. You don't need to pad the data, "Format32bppRgb" uses 4 bytes per pixel (or 32 bits per pixel as the name states, 8 bits == 1 byte).  "Format32bppRgb" is actually RGBX,  whereas your data seems to be stored "RGB" hence the 3 bytes per pixel

Try Format24bppRGB, this will be 3 bytes per pixel. and your stride will be width * 3

finally its worth mentioning the IntPtr part, you will have to keep a separate reference to that... if you want the bitmap to persist, I recommend looking at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782489/create-bitmap-from-a-byte-array-of-pixel-data

Comment: internally a bitmap width is evenly dividable by four.  Stride is normally bit depth * width but if that's not divisible by four, it's padded.

Comment: when I try to draw it I get this error `: A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format. (Parameter 'image')
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Image image)`

Answer (score 141):

You'll need to get those `bytes` into a `MemoryStream`:

```
Bitmap bmp;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

That uses the [`Bitmap(Stream stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor overload.

**UPDATE:** keep in mind that according to the documentation, and the source code I've been reading through, an `ArgumentException` will be thrown on these conditions:

```
stream does not contain image data or is null.
-or-
stream contains a PNG image file with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.
```

Comment: And then is it enough to write bmp.Save(c:\\image.jpg);    ??

Comment: I get same error message like @mario 's answer :  An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Parameter is not valid

Comment: @goGud, on what line?

Comment: '((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
'((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

These are from Debug

Comment: @goGud, **what line** is throwing the `ArgumentException`?

Comment: @goGud Maybe you should show us the code for creating the byte array from an image, as well.

Comment: bmp = new Bitmap(ms); this line throws exception

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud i think i have raw bytes

Comment: @goGud, based on the .NET source the only way you'd get this exception is if the `Stream` is `null`. Is the `byte[]` actually `null`?

Comment: no i also checked this it has value.. And also value of ms is same as byte[].

Comment: @goGud: then at this point you fall into one of the other two categories I've documented in my answer. It's not a valid image or it's a PNG that's got a single dimension that's too large.

Comment: @wondra I'm not sure how it doesn't answer the question, can you elaborate on your position?

Comment: Second try: according to comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782534/3096657) the stream should contain BMP, not byte array. Can you provide example how did you convert `byte[] imageData` to in-memory BMP data?

Comment: So just how is the height and width of that Bitmap specified?

Comment: @MikeC the actual height and width of the image should be defined in the metadata of the file format. The display height and width would be handled by the user interface.

Comment: No!  Don't dispose the stream!  From [`Bitmap(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap."

Comment: As @piedar pointed out, the stream should NOT be closed/disposed until after the bitmap is disposed.  However, if you are using a `MemoryStream`, then you don't have to worry about ever closing it, since the `MemoryStream` doesn't actually do anything when it's disposed anyway.  The [`System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertFrom`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=ImageConverter) method actually takes advantage of that fact, so it seems safe to make that assumption.  Do, simply `var bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imageData));` will suffice.

Comment: problem with this is that it wont convert an array to a bitmap, because there is no dimensional image (how width height should the image be). If you start with a bitmap and put it in a stream, you'll provide such info and if you have such a stream you can do the rverse as well, but such a stream is not a normal array its more close to an an object.

Answer (score 21):

Can be as easy as:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

image.Save("c:\\image.jpg");
```

---

Testing it out:

```
byte[] imageData;

// Create the byte array.
var originalImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\original.jpg");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    originalImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imageData = ms.ToArray();
}

// Convert back to image.
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    image.Save(@"C:\newImage.jpg");
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing another way of skinning the cat with the `static` accessor, but yes you'll want to get that `MemoryStream` wrapped in a `using`.

Comment: @goGud I have updated the answer. `System.Windows.Controls.Image` is a control to show an image. Here, it's the class `System.Drawing.Image` that is used.

Comment: Ty i have last question and i think it will be end. 

When i used your code I get this error while debug.


An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: @goGud It sounds like the byte array you're sending in to the `Image.FromStream` method is not a valid image.

Comment: @Mario it has an byte array which has 0-99999 and i think i need to use 8bit, 256 bppi.

Comment: No!  Don't dispose the stream!  From [`Image.FromStream(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x\(v=vs.110\).aspx): "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image."

Comment: @piedar, you're right in large. Just in this test case though the code is saving the image to disk so there's no use to keep the stream.

Comment: The problem here is that its not  a stream of raw RGB as in question.
To retrieve data no dimensions are given, it saves images just like any object can saved where the object itself allready was a image with makeup (ea dimensions pixelformat etc).

Answer (score 7):

In addition, you can simply convert `byte array` to `Bitmap`.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imgByte));
```

You can also get `Bitmap` from **file Path** directly.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(filePath));
```

Comment: error `ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.`

Comment: I got the same error message ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

Answer (score 2):

This was helpful to me: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1264492 (Reference answer)

I understand the question as follows:

- I have a byte array that contains pixel data e.g. in RGB format (24bit/pixel)
- From this raw pixel data I want to create a Bitmap

This code worked for me:

```
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
byte[] pixelArray = new byte[] {
  // Creation of the actual data is not in the scope of this answer
};

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

// Create a BitmapData and lock all pixels to be written 
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
// Copy the data from the byte array into BitmapData.Scan0
Marshal.Copy(pixelArray, 0, bmpData.Scan0, pixelArray.Length);

// Unlock the pixels
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

// Do something with your image, e.g. save it to disc
bmp.Save("c:\\temp\\mybmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer the OP wanted to interpret `imageData` byte array as the pixel buffer, rather than an already encoded bitmap stream as the most upvoted answer suggests. And though it works, it contains a lot of copies, as well as palette issues (*"And there is a problem with colors right now"*).

I actually happen to have a [drawing library](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) exactly for this purpose (among others). The platform-independent core library allows you to [interpret](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#self-allocating-vs-preallocated-buffers) any array of primitive types as a bitmap data:

```cs
// Unlike in the accepted answer, no extra buffer allocation or
// array copy happens in the background. Note that we can specify
// a palette for the indexed format so the colors will be interpreted correctly
using var myBitmap = BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(imageData, new Size(fWidth, fHeight),
    stride: fWidth, // stride is same as width because of the 8bpp pixel format
    pixelFormat: KnownPixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed,
    palette: Palette.Grayscale256());
```

`myBitmap` is now an [`IReadWriteBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IReadWriteBitmapData.htm) instance, allowing a lot of operations (just see the available extension methods). It also offers a pretty fast [`SetPixel`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IWritableBitmapData_SetPixel.htm) method, which respects the palette so in this particular case it turns any color to grayscale. But if you know the actual pixel format you can also can use the [`WriteRaw<T>`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IWritableBitmapDataRow_WriteRaw__1.htm) method to access the pixels directly.

And if you use the technology-specific packages such as the one for [GDI+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing) or [WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.Wpf/), then you can simply convert your buffer into known bitmap types such as [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_ReadableBitmapDataExtensions_ToBitmap.htm) or [`System.Windows.Media.WriteableBitmap`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Wpf_ReadableBitmapDataExtensions_ToWriteableBitmap.htm):

```cs
// the accepted answer creates two bitmaps due to the color problems where
// the 2nd one is a 32 bpp image. This solution is much faster, simpler, it avoids
// unnecessary allocations and uses parallel processing internally if possible
var systemBitmap = myBitmap.ToBitmap(); // or ToBitmapAsync, ToWriteableBitmap, etc.
```