# Return Bitmap with C++/CLI Wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, wrapper

I try to write a CLI wrapper for OpenCV, which returns a bitmap from a given OpenCV matrix. I use a function with a fix image inside the wrapper to test it:

```
Bitmap^ GetImage()
{
    Mat frame = imread("Image.png", 0);
    return gcnew Bitmap(frame.cols, frame.rows, 4 * frame.rows, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, IntPtr(frame.data));
}
```

My C# code contains the following code to store the image back:

```
Bitmap Test = Wrapper.GetImage();
Test.Save(@"C:\temp\Bla.bmp");
```

After executing the code, I´ve got this exception:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/79lqW.png]

How can I fix it? What is the reason for this exception?

Comment: What is the message translated to English please?

Comment: An Exception called "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException" in "System.Drawing.dll" appears.

Additional Informations: General Error in GDI+.

Comment: First try saving to the desktop, there may be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. Because the 'frame' variable goes out of scope when the function returns. Thus, the pointer is dead, and you have a GDI object with a pointer to garbage data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

> The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.

I am not sure what this Mat object is, but you get get the one dimensional row of bytes and do a Marshal::Copy() to the pre-allocated byte array (array^).

I would either return this array created from the Mat object and create the bitmap in C# like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555447/887584

Or you can of course do this in the C++ code if you want to keep separation of concerns, doing the same thing in C++:

```
auto stream = gcnew MemoryStream(bytes);
auto bitmap = gcnew Bitmap(stream);
delete stream;
return bitmap;
```