# Convert RGB array to image in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I know the rgb value of every pixel, and how can I create the picture by these values in C#? I've seen some examples like this:

```
public Bitmap GetDataPicture(int w, int h, byte[] data)
  {

  Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(this.width, this.height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
  Color c;

  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    c = Color.FromArgb(data[i]);
    pic.SetPixel(i%w, i/w, c);
  }

  return pic;
  }
```

But it does not works.
I have a two-dimensional array like this:

> 1 3 1 2 4 1 3 ...
> 2 3 4 2 4 1 3 ...
> 4 3 1 2 4 1 3 ...
> ...

Each number correspond to a rgb value, for example, 1 => {244,166,89}
2=>{54,68,125}.

Comment: you dont know how to create a byte array?? how do you create an array of anything... sometype[] myname = ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create bitmap from byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555394/how-to-create-bitmap-from-byte-array)

Comment: does the above example work?

Comment: what was your exact requirement?
you need to create a bitmap image with rgb of every pixel or create bytearrray from image

Comment: create a bitmap image with rgb of every pixel

Comment: you have rgb of every pixel... right? also you know the height and width for which the image to be created.. right?

Comment: yes.  Just donnt know how to convert it into a byte array.

Comment: Should I organize these values by row or column?

Comment: and by RGB or BGR?

Comment: how you have your rgb values now? i mean in which format? array/list/something

Comment: If i not mistaken,  are you have picture with indexed colors? I.e. picture is a array of bytes, where each byte value correspond to some 3-byte RGB color?

Comment: @Uthistran S. I've added the info.

Comment: @Alexander Kiselev Yes.

Comment: @hashtabe_0 I don't get it, really. The question makes it sound like you *have* a byte array and want to create the bitmap from it, the comments say that you *just donnt know how to convert it into a byte array*. So which one is it? Do you want to create the bitmap from an existing byte array or do you want to create the byte array from an existing bitmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try the following code, which uses an array of 256 `Color` entries for the palette (you have to create and fill this in advance):

```
public Bitmap GetDataPicture(int w, int h, byte[] data)
{
    Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            int arrayIndex = y * w + x;
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(
               data[arrayIndex],
               data[arrayIndex + 1],
               data[arrayIndex + 2],
               data[arrayIndex + 3]
            );
            pic.SetPixel(x, y, c);
        }
    }

    return pic;
}
```

I tend to iterate over the pixels, not the array, as I find it easier to read the double loop than the single loop and the modulo/division operation.

Comment: how to declare the palette variable?

Comment: @InsideMan Actually this was a mistake in my code. The "palette" variable should have been the "data" variable, which is w * h * 4 bytes long and contains the ARGB values for each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution very near to working code. Just you need the "palette" - i.e. set of 3-elements byte array, where each 3-bytes element contains {R, G, B} values.

```
    //palette is a 256x3 table
    public static Bitmap GetPictureFromData(int w, int h, byte[] data, byte[][] palette)
    {
      Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
      Color c;

      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
      {
          byte[] color_bytes = palette[data[i]];
          c = Color.FromArgb(color_bytes[0], color_bytes[1], color_bytes[2]);
          pic.SetPixel(i % w, i / w, c);
      }

      return pic;
    }
```

This code works for me, but it very slow.

If you create in-memory "image" of BMP-file and then use Image.FromStream(MemoryStream("image")), it code will be more faster, but it more complex solution.