# How to create a blank (white) BitmapImage

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I would like to write a programme to dynamically update the windows task bar icon at runtime by writing some custom text onto the icon. To do so I need to create a blank white BitmapImage, but this seems to be impossible...

All constructors want some URI, or Stream. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks alot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create bitmap from byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555394/how-to-create-bitmap-from-byte-array)

Comment: @izlin Why would it? [`BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) isn't mentioned anywhere on that question or its answers.

Comment: Thanks, but this link is about Bitmap, i'm asking about BitmapImage

Comment: Create an array, fill it with all `0xff` and then use the solution from the link

Comment: @FranzKafka My bad, thought Bitmap and BitmapImage were similar but I was wrong.

Comment: OP: it seems there is a `WriteableBitmap`, and it seems there are methods to convert this to a `BitmapImage`. I'm not sure if that answers your question though, as I've never used any of these (I'm mostly a backend dev) but hopefully the information might be helpful.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, type of icon is `ImageSource`, do you really need a `BitmapImage`?