# vb.net How to display an 8 bit image in a picture box from a byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image

I have a single array containing the image data acquired from a camera.
The array contains only the 8 bit data relating to each pixel. currently I perform the following to display the image on the picturebox:

```
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(CInt(width), CInt(height))
    Dim bufcnt As Integer = 0
    Dim mrow As Integer
    Dim mcol As Integer
    For mrow = 0 To height - 1
        For mcol = 0 To width - 1
            bm.SetPixel(mcol, mrow, Color.FromArgb(imageBuffer(bufcnt), imageBuffer(bufcnt), imageBuffer(bufcnt)))
            bufcnt = bufcnt + 1
        Next mcol
    Next mrow
    PCBIMG.Image = bm
```

However, on larger images this does take some time, is there a more efficient way of doing this that allows for realtime display of the image?

Comment: If you can understand C#, then : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560495/327083

Comment: sorry I'm not to familiar with C#, im still trying to get to grips with vb.net

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that uses `Marshal.Copy` to move the entire bitmap at once.  The bitmap format must be `Format8bppIndexed` so that you can move the raw data directly into the bitmap object rather than convert each pixel to 24bpp manually.  The 8bpp indexed format can actually display any 8-bit subset of 24-bit colours so you need to define a colour palette for the image.  I'm assuming you want greyscale, so the palette is just a 1:1 map.

For this you'll need the following imports :

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Then :

```
Function ConvertBytesToBitmap(ByVal inBytes() As Byte, _
                              ByVal imgWidth As Integer, _ 
                              ByVal imgHeight As Integer) As Bitmap

    Dim b As New Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)

    ' Define a greyscale colour palette
    Dim ncp As ColorPalette = b.Palette
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 255
        ncp.Entries(i) = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i)
    Next
    b.Palette = ncp

    ' Copy the bytes to the bitmap's data region
    Dim BoundsRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight)
    Dim bmpData As BitmapData = b.LockBits(BoundsRect, _
                                           ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, _
                                           b.PixelFormat)

    ' Bitmap.Scan0 returns a pointer to the image data array
    ' The data format is a 1D array, row-major format
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0

    Dim numberOfBytes As Integer = bmpData.Stride * b.Height

    Marshal.Copy(inBytes, 0, ptr, numberOfBytes)
    b.UnlockBits(bmpData)
    Return b

End Function
```

To show an example of usage, I've chosen a 400x200 pixel image and have filled it with a horizontal gradient :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    ' Create example image buffer for 400x200px image
    Dim imgBuffer(79999) As Byte

    ' Fill example image buffer with horizontal gradient
    For i = 0 To 199
        For j = 0 To 399
            imgBuffer(j + i * 400) = 255 * j / 400
        Next
    Next

    PictureBox1.Image = ConvertBytesToBitmap(imgBuffer, 400, 200)
End Sub
```

The function above is not fully optimized for your purposes, of course.  You could skip re-creating the greyscale palette each time and save a copy, either passing it in as an argument or building it into a class, etc.  This could save a bit of time.  Still, this should be several thousands of times faster than the code you are using, even if you create the colour palette each time.