# Retrieve image of picturebox in usercontrol to form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

**Usercontrol1**

```
private string lastName;    

public string LastName
{
    get { return lastName; }
    set
    {
        lastName = value;
        label1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
public void Gerar_codigo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT  tblCategory.Categoryname, tblProduct.Productname,tblProduct.Sinopse FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblCategory.Categoryid = tblProduct.Categoryid where tblCategory.Categoryname= '" + btn.Text + "'", cn);

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
        flowLayoutPanel2.Update();
        while (dr.Read())     
        {
            UserControl1 user = new UserControl1();
            user.Nnovo  = (string)dr["Productname"].ToString();///Adds the values ​​of the database in label1 the usercontrol

            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(user);//Load usercontrol1 in flowlayoutpanel
            flowLayoutPanel2.Update();

        } dr.Close();           
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Application.ExitThread();
    }

}
```

In my `UserControl` I have `label1` and `picturebox1`.

I set the `Label` but how can set the `PictureBox` to load image in form?

Help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the image to a byte array, create a bitmap of it and set to picturebox1's image.

Comment: Would have some example of creating bitmap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782489/create-bitmap-from-a-byte-array-of-pixel-data

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv