# Copying a byte array to a bitmap using unsafe block

Tags: c#, performance, image-processing

I'm trying to squeeze the best performance out of some imaging code and I've hit a wall.

As far as my knowledge goes it should be possible to speed up the process using pointers but my experience with them is very limited and finding good documentation to read and understand is proving difficult.

Am I correct? Could someone show an annotated example of the code converted to help me understand the process.

```
    public void UpdatePixelIndexes(IEnumerable<byte[]> lineIndexes)
    {
        int width = this.Image.Width;
        int height = this.Image.Height;

        IEnumerator<byte[]> indexesIterator = lineIndexes.GetEnumerator();
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < height; rowIndex++)
        {
            indexesIterator.MoveNext();
            BitmapData data = this.Image.LockBits(Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, rowIndex, width, rowIndex + 1), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(indexesIterator.Current, 0, data.Scan0, width);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Image.UnlockBits(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just lock and unlock once? You'd have to pass data.Scan0 + data.Stride * rowIndex then, but that's not a real problem.

Comment: http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Comment: @harold could you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely you actually need `unsafe` here. As suggested, you should just stop locking/unlocking the bitmap for every scan line. Instead, do this:

```
public void UpdatePixelIndexes(IEnumerable<byte[]> lineIndexes)
{
    int width = this.Image.Width;
    int height = this.Image.Height;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    BitmapData data = this.Image.LockBits(Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    try
    {
        foreach (byte[] scanLine in lineIndexes)
        {
            Marshal.Copy(scanLine, 0,
               IntPtr.Add(data.Scan0, data.Stride * rowIndex), width);

            if (++rowIndex >= height)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Image.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's certainly an improvement. I'd like to avoid duplicating the memory by using Marshal.Copy hence why I was looking for unsafe usage if possible.

Comment: `Marshal.Copy()` shouldn't be duplicating data. It should just copy the bytes from one place to the other. Do you have some reason to believe it is duplicating data?

Comment: I just thought that's what it did. This comment seemed to back that up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782489/create-bitmap-from-a-byte-array-of-pixel-data#comment24719278_6782489

Comment: First, that comment is out of context and it may or may not be the case that the commenter intended to mean that the copy of the data was made by `Marshal.Copy()` itself (i.e. they could be talking about the need to allocate memory in the form of a new `Bitmap` object). Second, even if the commenter did mean that `Marshal.Copy()` performs an allocation of some temporary, intermediate buffer, that doesn't mean the commenter knows what they are talking about.

Comment: True that. I'm happy to assign this as the answer.

Comment: I think it copies one line for a short time, no problem there.